# First connection to sql server takes 15 minutes on LAN

Tags: sql-server

When I open SSMS and connect to a database on a corporate LAN it takes 15 minutes for the first connection. Additional connections with SSMS take less than 1 second. After connecting queries execute quickly.
I have tried connecting to several servers that are running SQL 2008 and SQL 2012 and SQL 2016, I have use my windows account and SQL logins.
I am doing maintenance work on a Winforms application and experience the same delay while running the application in Visual Studio. When I debug and step through the code the delay happens when I hit the Using statement, not the connection.open() that comes after and on the first time data is requested from the database only. Additional requests happen quickly.

```
Using cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(SQL_CONN_STRING), cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSQL)
        cn.Open()
```

The application is deployed out to a network share and users run it from a shortcut on their desktop. It still works for all the users but not for me when I hit the shortcut from my desktop. If I remote to a server then hit the shortcut it works without delay. 
This application ran fine until last Wednesday. One change I made that day was to install VMware Horizon. Another change was to add a WebEx client. I have since removed both, that did not help.
I like a good mystery but this one has me stumped. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a network issue. Can you install Management Studio locally?

Comment: Try adding the server you are connecting to into your hostfile, this will make sure it is not an DNS issue

Comment: I have Management Studio installed locally. I only get this delay locally. From another server on the network all is good. Other local users also have no delay.

Comment: I tried adding the hosts file entry. It did not help. DNS seems to resolve quickly such as when I do a ping.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by the VMWare client install. The procedure here resolved the issue for me:
[VMWare support site](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2105977)

Comment: wish I could upvote this more - such a needle in a haystack to find. thank you!